# MatPlotLib how to make plots zoom in and out

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and data visualization and here is the question: I have a plot built with points and lables on them, but since the range between points in general is TOO high but within a groop is too low a have a severe ovellapping =( (can be see on an image). Can anyone suggest either a nice python visualisation lib for such cases or maybe a solution how I can zoom in / out to show those groups closer ? Thanks P.S. labels of axis were messed up I know.

[image: Generated plot]

this is how I visualize my plot:

```
 # here we concatinate set of arrays using numpy to display they in the graph
    allAvg = np.concatenate((df['Avg']), axis=None)
    allYears = np.concatenate((df['Year']), axis=None)
    allStocs = np.concatenate((df['Stock']), axis=None)

    minValueAvg = min(allAvg)
    maxValueAvg = max(allAvg)
    start = time.time()
    print("Time taken to build plot")
    for ind, type in enumerate(df['Stock']):
        start = time.time()
        print("Time taken to go through one Stock and put it on a plot")
        for i, z in enumerate(df['Avg'][ind]):
            x = allAvg[i]
            y = allYears[i]
            plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.5, marker='D', color='green')
            plt.text(x + 0.1, y + 0.1, type, fontsize=4)
            end = time.time()
            print(end - start)
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Average Adjustment Close Price')
    plt.title('Stock market graph')
    plt.legend()
    # show plot right away
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, that would help a lot to know your situation better.

Comment: @Lepakk Done, please check the update

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful, in case you want a zoomed-in subplot inside your plot: https://scipython.com/blog/inset-plots-in-matplotlib/
But in case you want some sort of **interactive** usage, you can try using ````plt.show()```` which should open your figure and you can use the zoom in tool.

Comment: @rfaenger but I'm using plot show, you can see it in the code. The only thing it zoom it like if it is a picture, not an interactive graph. So if I zoom in I want my x and y axis scalings change as well, like if I zoom in the step giong to change from every year to months and than days, you see what I mean ?

Comment: Okay - I dont think this can be accomplished in an easy way using matplotlib. Maybe ````plotly```` is something which is going to help you. For e.g. https://plot.ly/python/zoom-events/